# How to iterate through rows in one dataframe and assgin value

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I have a data frame called resource

Resource Xy usage was ended at 06-12-2018 11:00
.Till the usage of the resource Xy by Per1 for P1, Per8 for P2 cannot use the resource. I want to copy end value resource Xy used in Project P1 to start column for Project P2 used by Per8 replacing the default value. end column will be (start time + allocated time for that person). I want to iterate though out the rows again and again till all default value (1970-01-01 00:00:00) are replaced

[image]
 
`t_mx = t_m.groupby(['Resource']).agg({'end' : max }).reset_index()
t_mx['end'] = t_m.apply(lambda row: row['new']+row['Time'] if row['new'] != pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00:00') else pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),axis = 1)`

I have used this above code to create a column

[image]

I am not able to get how to proceed further

Project Resource    Person  Allocation Time start   end
P1  Xy  Per 1   04:00   06-12-2018 08:00    06-12-2018 11:00
P1  Z   Per 2   05:00   06-12-2018 08:00    06-12-2018 12:00
P1  Y   Per 3   07:00   06-12-2018 08:00    06-12-2018 18:00
P1  X   Per 1   03:50   06-12-2018 08:00    06-12-2018 12:00
P2  X   Per 6   02:20   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Y   Per 7   01:25   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Xy  Per 8   02:30   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Xy  Per 9   14:00   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  X   Per 7   12:35   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Y   Per 6   11:10   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Z   Per 11  13:45   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P2  Z   Per 12  10:00   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00
P3  X   Per 5   07:30   01-01-1970 00:00    01-01-1970 00:00

Comment: What is the allocated time for each person ?

Comment: It varies. It will be giving in hours. I have added the column. Please go through through it again

Comment: So you don't have say a table that has all the allocated times ? It would be helpul to copy and paste it if so

Comment: I am having trouble copy pasting the table. please go through https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zjC-JiEel1O5TyYeZArgzdQXe0Wu4yGUakWZ98Mi70I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we get the data in pandas and convert the colums to suitable types:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """
Project Resource    Person  Allocation Time start   end
P1  Xy  Per 1   4:00    06-12-2018 8:00 06-12-2018 11:00
P1  Z   Per 2   5:00    06-12-2018 8:00 06-12-2018 12:00
P1  Y   Per 3   7:00    06-12-2018 8:00 06-12-2018 18:00
P1  X   Per 1   3:50    06-12-2018 8:00 06-12-2018 12:00
P2  X   Per 6   2:20    01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Y   Per 7   1:25    01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Xy  Per 8   2:30    01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Xy  Per 9   14:00   01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  X   Per 7   12:35   01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Y   Per 6   11:10   01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Z   Per 11  13:45   01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P2  Z   Per 12  10:00   01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
P3  X   Per 5   7:30    01-01-1970 0:00 01-01-1970 0:00
"""

t_m = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\t')

t_m = t_m.assign(
    start=lambda f: pd.to_datetime(f.start),
    end=lambda f: pd.to_datetime(f.end),
    alloc_time=lambda f: pd.to_timedelta(f["Allocation Time"].apply(lambda x: x+':00')))
```

We iterate over the groups of resource, each time using the previous end as the new start:

```py
out = t_m.copy()
for resource, group in t_m.groupby('Resource'):
    start = group.start.iloc[0]
    for ix, row in group.iterrows():
        out.loc[ix, 'start'] = start
        start = start + row['alloc_time']
        out.loc[ix, 'end'] = start

out = out.drop('Allocation Time', axis=1)
print(out)
```

```
   Project Resource  Person               start                 end alloc_time
0       P1       Xy   Per 1 2018-06-12 08:00:00 2018-06-12 12:00:00   04:00:00
1       P1        Z   Per 2 2018-06-12 08:00:00 2018-06-12 13:00:00   05:00:00
2       P1        Y   Per 3 2018-06-12 08:00:00 2018-06-12 15:00:00   07:00:00
3       P1        X   Per 1 2018-06-12 08:00:00 2018-06-12 11:50:00   03:50:00
4       P2        X   Per 6 2018-06-12 11:50:00 2018-06-12 14:10:00   02:20:00
5       P2        Y   Per 7 2018-06-12 15:00:00 2018-06-12 16:25:00   01:25:00
6       P2       Xy   Per 8 2018-06-12 12:00:00 2018-06-12 14:30:00   02:30:00
7       P2       Xy   Per 9 2018-06-12 14:30:00 2018-06-13 04:30:00   14:00:00
8       P2        X   Per 7 2018-06-12 14:10:00 2018-06-13 02:45:00   12:35:00
9       P2        Y   Per 6 2018-06-12 16:25:00 2018-06-13 03:35:00   11:10:00
10      P2        Z  Per 11 2018-06-12 13:00:00 2018-06-13 02:45:00   13:45:00
11      P2        Z  Per 12 2018-06-13 02:45:00 2018-06-13 12:45:00   10:00:00
12      P3        X   Per 5 2018-06-13 02:45:00 2018-06-13 10:15:00   07:30:00
```